# Pygame window not responding because of user inputs into console

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to the pygame module and what I was trying to do here is first authenticate users to the game, before the pygame window opens. This is a snippet of the code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))

...

def create_username(): 
username = input("Enter a new username: ")
file.write("\n")
file.write(username)
print("You now have a username! ")
return username

def existing_username(): 
username = input("Enter your username: ")
for line in file:
    if username in line:
        print(f"Welcome back {username}!")
        return username
    else:
        print("That is not an existing username.")

player1_name = input("PLAYER ONE: Do you have an account? (y/n) ")
if player1_name.lower() == "y":
    player1_name = existing_username()
elif player1_name.lower()  == 'n':
    player1_name = create_username()

player2_name = input("PLAYER TWO: Do you have an account? (y/n) ")
if player2_name.lower() == "y":
    player2_name = existing_username()
elif player2_name.lower() == 'n':
    player2_name = create_username()

player_one = player(player1_name)
player_two = player(player2_name)

run = True
while run:
    win.fill((255,255,255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

The input part works fine on the console, but the pygame window does not respond (it just crashes). If I comment out the whole input section, the pygame window opens up without any issues. Can anyone help me fix this please, thank you!
[Not responding window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd4DK.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the is related to the user input? To verify it, for debugging have you tried commenting out the user input section and running the rest of the program with default values to fill in for the user input? That would help you narrow down where things were going wrong.

Comment: Please add any error messages from the "it just crashes" result.  There is nothing in your main PyGame loop that will cause a crash (assuming `win` is correctly initialised).  Maybe also add the PyGame window initialisation code into the question.

Comment: @Kingsley no error message comes up in python, it just says ‘windows is not responding’ and the window closes. I think it is correctly initialised as when I do remove the input section it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: @Glenn Mackintosh I have tried excluding the input section from the code and the pygame window opens up perfectly fine. I shall edit in the window initialisation code into the question though just in case there are any errors.

Comment: You get "is not responding" because your code is not processing the event loop.  Something (not in the code above) is calling-out of the main loop but never returning.  Maybe include the full window initialisation and main-loop code into your question.

Comment: @Kingsley Hi, I think I've realised why the not responding window keeps coming up, is it perhaps because run only = True after the input, and hence only once the inputs are filled in, the window starts responding again?

Comment: Yes, possibly.  You could try not opening your pygame window until after the two text inputs.  You could also split your program in two, and verify that the loop-part works fine on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your Game Loop : fill the screen (win) after the event for loop

```
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    win.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I am also assuming that you have the initial boilerplate working i.e initializing pygame and setting up the screen(win)

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Engineer Lenny Thank you for the advice, but I think I've sorted out the problem by just moving the initialising pygame and setting up the screen after the whole input section, and now it works fine.